# Why are my floating action buttons not working properly in my ViewPager?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

I have a ViewPager set up with my app and am trying to also set two floating action buttons, a left one and a right one, to do the same thing as the ViewPager, so that the user has a choice in terms of navigation. I'm trying to have it set so that the left button is invisible on the first page, and the right button is invisible on the last page, but the appearances of the buttons seem to be sporadic. I've tried debugging the app, and upon testing each situation, the appropriate code is executed, so I can't understand why this behavior is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

TestFragment:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ID = "Id";
    private int Id;
    private String title;
    private TextView titleTV;
    private String description;
    private TextView descriptionTV;
    private int number;
    private TextView numberTV;
    private FloatingActionButton leftBtn;
    private FloatingActionButton rightBtn;

    public static TestFragment newInstance(int Id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_ID, Id);

        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

        Id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ID);
        title = Test.testData[Id].getTitle();
        description = Test.testData[Id].getDescription();
        number = Test.testData[Id].getNumber();

        titleTV = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTV.setText(title);

        descriptionTV = view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        descriptionTV.setText(description);

        numberTV = view.findViewById(R.id.number);
        numberTV.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        leftBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.left_btn);
        rightBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.right_btn);
        toggleButtons();

        leftBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                testViewPager.setCurrentItem(--index);
                toggleButtons();
            }
        });

        rightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                testViewPager.setCurrentItem(++index);
                toggleButtons();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void toggleButtons() {
        if(index == 0) {
            leftBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if(index == Test.testData.length - 1) {
            rightBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            leftBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rightBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

TestPagerActivity:

```
public class TestPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static int index;
    public static ViewPager testViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_pager);

        index = (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_ID);

        testViewPager = findViewById(R.id.test_view_pager);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        testViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return TestFragment.newInstance(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return Test.testData.length;
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < Test.testData.length; i++) {
            if(i == index) {
                testViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but is this line correct? `index = (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_ID);` I mean the key `EXTRA_ID` is used to get the extra that is called `index`, so maybe this is causing some issues.

Comment: I should think so. I was thinking that maybe I could use `ARG_ID` as the key, but the app crashes if I do that. Or do you mean that the way I'm retrieving the data from the extra is incorrect?

Comment: No, the way of retrieving is correct, just the name is misleading: `EXTRA_ID` is the key for the value `index` and I thought that You have a different key for that value, like `EXTRA_INDEX`. That is because I thought there might something wrong because of the naming. Have You debugged the app and checked if the value of `index` is always correct?

Comment: The key `EXTRA_ID` should be the correct key, since the only keys I have are `ARG_ID` and `EXTRA_ID`. I did try debugging the app and the value of `index` seems correct; when I set a breakpoint on `testViewPager.setCurrentItem(--index);` and click the left FAB on the second array item, `index` changes to 0 after that line executes. I don't know if this is relevant or not, but the app eventually goes to View.class and says that the "source code does not match the bytecode."

Comment: This part with View.class is irrelevant, don't worry. I would suggest to You to implement the `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback.onPageSelected` instead of creating separate `onClickListeners`, because the callback would also handle swipes, not only button clicks. In that callback You would just call `toggleButtons`.

Comment: Would that require me to change the existing ViewPager to ViewPager2? I was trying to follow the Android Developers migration documentation, but I am stuck on the constructor parameter for the adapter class. I'm trying to pass a `FragmentActivity` object, but I'm not sure how to initialize it. After that, would I be correct in assuming that I just need to pass the index to `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallBack.onPageSelected`?

Comment: No, I think that the callback is available in the first ViewPager, so You don't need to migrate. Also the callbacks' argument is an index, but it is not You that is providing it - You will have it in Your callback. The index will be the one of the new selected page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but I have my TestPagerActivity class implementing `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`. I've implemented `onPageScrolled`, `onPageSelected`, and `onPageScrollStateChanged`, and I called `toggleButtons` in `onPageSelected`. The FABs are still not behaving correctly. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, at this point I won't be able to help, because I'm away from home and have no way to test any code. But if You have a new implementation of Your problem You can try asking a new question with updated code.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but I was playing around with the code some more, and I found that putting the buttons in activity_test_pager, implementing `testViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener`, and putting the code from `toggleButtons` in the `onPageScrolled` method makes it work as it should. To that end, I was able to get an implementation of the buttons that works for me. But I do appreciate your help in all this.

Comment: Very nice to hear that!